# How to find superblock?

Tags: lvm, partitioning, storage, fdisk

I am trying to find the superblock with `dumpe2fs` command, but with this output there is no information about superblocks.

Comment: i don't know what you want; but `man dumpe2fs` says -h "only display the superblock information and not any of the block group..."

Comment: @guiverc dumpe2fs can error out and not show the superblock ;) The answer uses the "backup" location for the superblock (dumpe2fs does not use that one).

Answer (score 2):

You can also find the superblock with

```
mkfs.ext4 -n /dev/sda
mkfs.ext2 -n /dev/sda
```

(pick ext4/ext2 if your system is ext4/ext2; REPLACE sda with your disk). From the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs.ext4):

> `-n` Causes mke2fs to not actually create a filesystem, but display what it would do if it were to create a filesystem. **This can be used to determine the location of the backup superblocks** for a particular filesystem, so long as the mke2fs parameters that were passed when the filesystem was originally created are used again.

Repairing

```
fsck -b 11111 /dev/sda
```

where `11111` is the superblock, and sda the partition (REPLACE both with what you need).

Comment: trying with mkfs.ext2 coz my fs is ext2

Comment: not working after mkfs.ext2 command ask for wipe all data from partition

Comment: You did not include the `-n`: "Causes mke2fs to not actually create a filesystem" ? man page for ext2 is the same: https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs.ext2

Comment: root@aniket-VirtualBox:/home/aniket# mkfs.ext2 -n /dev/sda1
mke2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
/dev/sda1 contains a ext2 file system
 last mounted on /boot on Wed May  9 14:14:10 2018
Proceed anyway? (y,n)

Comment: How is that "ask(ing) for wipe all data from partition"?

Comment: i think mkfs is only use for apply fs on block not for checking super-block information

Comment: Then explain the "-n" option to me ;-) That options shows the location of the superblock based on the --backup-- it created when making the filesystem. In case tools error out you can use that one since it is saved elsewhere it is likely to be corrupted if your superblock is.

Comment: for this option check man page u will get all information related -n